# despite having same number of elements my code is showing compilation error in matlab

Tags: matlab

In my code I've taken time interval of 0.01 seconds from 0.01 to 10 units of time(basically it's the simulation of Amplitude Modulated Wave).
Both `ym` and `t` array contains `1000` elements.
My code is:

```
Am= 1;
Ac= 5;
Fm= 0.2;
Fc= 2;
t= 0.01:0.01:10;
ym= zeros(1, 1000);
for i=1:1:1000
    ym(i)= Am*sin(2*pi*Fm*t(i));
end
yc= zeros(1, 1000);
for i=1:1:1000
    yc(i)= Ac*sin(2*pi*Fc*t(i));
end
ymod= zeros(1, 1000);
for i=1:1:1000
    ymod(i)= (Ac + ym(i))*sin(2*pi*Fc*t(i));
end

subplot(2,2,1);
plot(t, ymod);
subplot(2,2,2);
plot(t, ym);
subplot(2,2,3);
plot(t, yc);
```

the error shown is

> In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be
>   the same.
>
> Error in project_code (line 8)
>       ym(i)= Am*sin(2*pi* Fm *t(i));

(I would like to mention, my program run successfully 1st time, but after I recompiled it showed the error)
help me!

Comment: This code runs without error and creates 3 plots as expected. Please restart your MATLAB or at least use `clear all` and retry. I am voting to close this question as not reproducible

Comment: Same, could not reproduce shown error. If you had overwritten `Am`, `Fm` or `pi` with a vector it would produce this error.

Comment: Thank you , please do not downvote , I faced that's why I asked, pardon